# Special characters 158 and 159 stopping my functions in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, special-characters

I am having issues with the two special characters 158 (U+009E "Private message") and 159 (U+009F "Application program command").
My issue started with a function in Clisp that I have to write for a class, I need to print out a string characters from 0 to 256 using `(code-char *number*)`. The code I wrote works and has been validated by my professor.

But on my end, on four different computers, and on different versions of Ubuntu (20.04, 22.04, 22.10, 23.04, 23.10), the string of character just stops when it reaches the character 158 and it just hangs and never finishes the string. If I try to print characters 158 or 159 on their own the same happens in my terminal.

I checked in python if I could print those characters with `print('\u009e')` and `print('\u009f')` and it works in IDLE but if I do it directly from the terminal the same issue happens.

I'm a bit lost as to why that may happen and I was wondering if anyone had a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

`0x9e` (PM) and `0x9f` (APC) are [C1 controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C1_controls) codes - an 8-bit extension of the ASCII [C0 controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_controls). As noted in [Control Bytes, Characters, and Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Control-Bytes_-Characters_-and-Sequences), in an ANSI VTxxx compatible terminal they (and a few others) introduce a *string mode*, that needs to be terminated by a corresponding `0x9c` (ST) string termination code:

> ```
> Some controls (such as OSC ) introduce a string mode, which is ended
> on a ST  (string terminator).
> .
> .
> .
> If an application does not send the string terminator, that is also
> an error from the standpoint of a user.
> ```

So likely your terminal is consuming the remaining bytes from your program, awaiting the expected ST.

Comment: Knowing this, would it be possible to circumvent this, or outright prevent my terminal from interpreting these characters as control characters when I'm using Clisp or Python3?

Comment: @BigLiquidCat it may be possible - perhaps that is something you could discuss with your professor or TA?